# Mocking a method inside a non-mocked method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock a method that is being called inside another method that is being unit tested. 
However, the mock is not working properly and I am getting an `UnknownHostException` that I would get if i never mocked the inside method in the first place. It might be my throws declarations as I am unaware how else to do it. Any help is appreciated.

My test is this so far:

```
@Test
public void testServiceValidHost() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HealthService service = new HealthService();
    HealthService spy = Mockito.spy(service);

    when(spy.getHTTPResponse("http://" + HOST + "/health")).thenReturn(SOMESTATUS);

    String actual = spy. executeHealthCheck(HOST);
    assertEquals(SOMESTATUS, actual);
}
```

The method I am testing is `executeHealthCheck`, and i want to mock `getHTTPResponse`

```
public String executeHealthCheck(String host) {
    try {
        String responseBody = getHTTPResponse("http://" + host + "/health");
        return responseBody;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        ...
        return "Invalid Host";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
        return "Error";
    }
}

public String getHTTPResponse(String url) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    response = client.execute(httpGet);
    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    return responseBody.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider mocking the class and arranging for the method under test to be actually called while stubbing the desired members.

For example

```
@Test
public void testServiceValidHost() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    //Arrange    
    HealthService service = Mockito.mock(HealthService.class);

    when(service.executeHealthCheck(HOST)).callRealMethod();
    when(service.getHTTPResponse("http://" + HOST + "/health")).thenReturn(SOMESTATUS);

    //Act
    String actual = service.executeHealthCheck(HOST);

    //Assert
    assertEquals(SOMESTATUS, actual);
}
```

However according to the docs, one of the `Important gotcha on spying real objects!`

> Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use `when(Object)` for stubbing spies. Therefore when using spies please consider *doReturn|Answer|Throw()* family of methods for stubbing.

```
@Test
public void testServiceValidHost() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    //Arrange
    HealthService service = new HealthService();
    HealthService spy = Mockito.spy(service);

    //You have to use doReturn() for stubbing
    doReturn(SOMESTATUS).when(spy).getHTTPResponse("http://" + HOST + "/health");

    //Act
    String actual = spy.executeHealthCheck(HOST);

    //Assert
    assertEquals(SOMESTATUS, actual);
}
```

Comment: Are there any major benefits for one over the other?